# aggregate row values based on where clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, pandas

I want to combine rows based on `col c` from below and sum their `value` column data. The rows are color coded by how they should be combined.

This needs to happen where `col a` `col b` and `date` fields match and it can only happen where `col c` = 'thing 1' or 'thing 2'. I don't want to combine matching rows for anything beyond `thing 1` or `thing 2`.

[image]

**First question**, is this more easily accomplished in SQL or Pandas?

**Second question:** in whichever is easiest, how would I accomplish this?

My SQL attempt:

```
select col_a, col_b, date, SUM(value::numeric) as thing_1_thing_2 from mytable where col_c = 'thing 1' or col_c = 'thing 2' group by col_a, col_b, date;
```

But this doesn't get me summations I was expecting. Also, aggregating as such removes the columns I still need from the output (such as the rows not highlighted above). I just need the colored rows merged, all else stays equal.

Comment: @DanielGale how do I `sum` a text field? Also, the `where` clause (as specified above) should be here too right?

Comment: Sorry. read aggregate as sum..  One moment.

Comment: @DanielGale I need to aggregate `value` column based on `col c`, were `col c` = 'thing 1` or `thing 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just select your `thing 1` and `thing 2` rows and aggregate those using `string_agg()` to do concatenate your values. THEN `UNION` that with all of your non-`thing 1/thing 2` rows:

```
SELECT
    colA,
    colB,
    string_agg(colC,' ') as colC,
    date,
    sum(Value) as Value
FROM myTable
WHERE colC IN ('thing 1', 'thing 2')
GROUP BY colA, colB, date


UNION ALL

SELECT colA, colB, colC, date, value 
FROM myTable
WHERE colC NOT IN ('thing 1', 'thing 2')
```

Alternatively you could toss a CASE statement into the mix and do this in a single pass:

```
SELECT
    colA,
    colB,
    CASE WHEN colC IN ('thing 1', 'thing 2') THEN 'Thing 1 Thing 2` ELSE colC END as colC,
    date,
    sum(Value) as Value
FROM myTable
GROUP BY colA, 
    colB, 
    CASE WHEN colC IN ('thing 1', 'thing 2') THEN 'Thing 1 Thing 2` ELSE colC END,
    date
```

I think the first one is more scalable and you don't have to monkey with hard-coded strings, just WHERE clauses.

Comment: `GROUP BY` followed by `WHERE` throws syntax error whereas `WHERE` followed by `GROUP BY` does not

Comment: Sorry @Growler I've fixed.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
SELECT colA, colB, colC, date, SUM(value) FROM table
WHERE colC in ('thing 1', 'thing2')
GROUP BY colA, colB, colC, date
```